# Spring Boot - YML config - Erase entry when merging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I have a base YML config for my app, in the class path that looks like this:

```
hello-world:
  values:
    bar:
      name: bar-name
      description: bar-description
    foo:
      name: foo-name
      description: foo-description
```

hello-world contains a map from string to POJO called values. I want to override the settings in hello-world, in particular I want to delete an entry. So on the local directory where I run the app I have this application.yml:

```
hello-world:
  values:
    bar:
      name: bar-name
      description: bar-description

source: from-the-local-dir
```

But this doesn't work, because when my local config overrides the existing one, the maps are merged into one and the original entry "foo" is kept. Is there a way to explicitly delete entries from a config map in spring yml?

PS: I can see that the local file get picked up, by modifying the the "bar" entry in the local file. Here's the full code, I've added a "source" config to tell which file was loaded last:

```
@Import(PlayGround.Config.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class PlayGround {

    @Autowired
    Config config;

    @Value("${source}")
    String source;

    public void start() {
        System.out.println(config);
        System.out.println(source);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(PlayGround.class, args);
        PlayGround playGround = context.getBean(PlayGround.class);
        playGround.start();
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hello-world")
    public static final class Config {
        Map<String, Information> values = new HashMap<String, Information>();

        public Map<String, Information> getValues() {
            return values;
        }

        public void setValues(Map<String, Information> values) {
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                    .add("values", values)
                    .toString();
        }
    }

    public static final class Information {

        String name;
        String description;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                    .add("name", name)
                    .add("description", description)
                    .toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot by default takes file from src/main/resource/application.yml
You can declare config/application.yml and those config will override application.yml in src/main/resources

You can just try src/main/resources/application.yml:

```
hello-world:
  bar: 
    name: bar-name
    description: bar-description
  foo: 
    name: foo-name
    description: foo-description
```

And config/application.yml

```
  hello-world:
      bar: 
        name: bar-name
        description: bar-description
```

I think this can help
So when you will run your application config/application.yml will override your existing src/main/resources/application.yml

You can completely remove hello-world from config/application.yml
But it will throw a runtime exception something like :

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'hello-world.foo' in value "${hello-world.foo}
```

To fix it you can apply injecting value like:
@Value("${hello-world.foo:}")
where after ':' you can define default value

You can leave in config/application.yml empty fields

```
hello-world:
  bar: 
    name: bar-name
    description: bar-description
  foo: 
    name:
    description:
```

By default if you will not specify all values in foo will be empty('') and then you can filter and remove entry with empty values from your map.
Also you can look into this class:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/YamlProcessor.ResolutionMethod.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that the merging process will merge the two maps together. So the map from src/main/resources/application.yml will be updated with the entries from config/application.yml. It works fine if I want to change the content of the 'bar' entry, but if I want to erase bar all together it doesn't work

Comment: Just don declare hello-world: at all in config/application.yml

Comment: Hey again It doesn't cut it. I'm trying to find a way to delete entries in map of settings. I've edited my answer to be more clear. I can see that I can override my settings with a local application.yml, but I haven't been able to set that settings file to explicitely delete map entries. The map entries from the classpath directory always linger.

Comment: OK, so the only way is to leave the value blanks and erase them manually. Regarding the ResolutionMethod, how do you specify which one to use?

Comment: I don’t know exactly it need deep investigation about how YamlParser works thanks

Comment: I can investigate if you want )