# Spring boot application configuration question

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have following structure of my application

```
----
   | 
   |____SpringBootApplicationA
        |
        |
        |___module-1
        |___module-2
```

Each module has its own configuration, For example, module-1 is library that talks to mysql, it has its configuration (connection string, username, password,etc...)

Now I want to represent this configuration in the form of Java POJO in module-1. `application.yml` and a bean that read configuration and sets the values.

For example

```
class Module1Config {

  private String key1;
  private String key2;

  // getters & setters
}
```

`application.yml` at module-1

```
key1: val1
key2: val2
```

now as a consumer of module-1, `SpringBootApplicationA` will receive module-1's configuration which is what set as default by module-1.

On the consumer side it will have application configuration like this

```
someKey1: someVal1
someKey2: someVal2
module-1:
  key1: overrideVal1
```

and when initialization happens of module-1's beans, I want the values to be seen as

```
key1: overrideVal1
key2: val2
```

How to configure spring boot to respect default values and override them ?

---

**Edit**

```
class AppConfig {

  private String key1;
  private int key2;

  private Module1Config conf;

  // getters + setters

}
```

This is my example application config, as you can see it has some specific to application config and other configs it is leveraging from other modules.

I want `conf` object to get assigned default set of value from module1 and then whatever application has specified as an override

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring boot by default loads application.yml file 
from src/main/resources
You can declare another application.yml file in 
config folder of root path and configuration from 
config folder will override configuration from src/main/resources

Config locations are searched in reverse order. By default, the configured locations are classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/. The resulting search order is the following:

file:./config/
file:./
classpath:/config/
classpath:/

Here is link from official documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

I think it’s helpful

Comment: Thanks Mykhalio, I made an edit to the question. I saw this document. I don't think it satisfies the scenario I mentioned.

Comment: I was asking question about something same here is link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189279/spring-boot-yml-config-erase-entry-when-merging/53189491#53189491